# How to use LIKE in a VBA SQL Query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So for my task, I have to search a Contacts Table for an Active Source, using a LIKE command. I have tried the following queries:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Contacts.ActiveSource LIKE '%" & val & "%'"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Contacts.ActiveSource LIKE '*" & val & "*'"
```

where val is the variable that stores what I am searching for. Both of the above return an error. I am new to VBA, so I am not sure what the issue is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *What* exactly are you searching? how are you executing the SQL? What is the error?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: is this code syntactically correct-  `LIKE '%" & val & "%'"`

Comment: "Both of the above return an error", what is the error message?, is it an error from vba or the database engine?

Comment: Might `val` contain an apostrophe? This condition would produce a syntactically incorrect sql statement.

Comment: It is an error from VBA. The error message is as follows: Syntax error in query expression 'Contacts.ActiveSource LIKE '*...'*"

Comment: val does not contain a apostrophe

Comment: @user1136610 Does the second example generate the same error?  Access does not support `%` but `*` should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, the same syntax error is returned

Comment: Which line gives the error? Surely not the one you show. Put a `Stop` statement before the line that gives the error. Go to the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) and type `?strSQL`, copy that sql statement and paste it into a new query in Access. That will give you a clue what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[`Val`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Val-Function-e5e1f21b-22f9-41c9-bd0a-fe55b767f603) is a function name. Use a different variable name like `strVal`.